# Solve state space equations

Tags: equation-solving

I never used Mathematica before. But I need to solve this system of equations for xt0, xt1, xt2, t1, t2. Everything else is given.

[image]

xt1,xt0, xt2 are 5x1 matrices. t1 and t2 are numbers. The code below is what I currently have to solve it.

[image]

I tried to get the relationship between the variables by using Solve for each equation. Then I join them into one list and use another Solve to get to the final result. But it gives me nothing as you can see in the very last line.

Am I approaching the problem correctly? Is there another way to solve this problem easier? Please let me know if I need to give you more info.

---

Here is the code that you can copy to test.

```
Cr = 109*10^(-9); Lr= 29.8*10^(-6); Ls = 0.01*10^(-9);Lm =565*10^(-6); n = 16; CL = 2200*10^(-6); 
Vin = 400; Vout = 12; Iout = 23; Vref = 12; k =1; f0= 90*10^3;

u ={Vin, Vref};

vD = 0.7;
kdi = vD/Vref; ki = 50000; Kp = 1000;
k1 = (n/Lr)*((1/k)+kdi);
k2 = (n/Lm)*((1/k)+kdi);
k3 = 1+(Ls/Lm )+(Ls/Lr); RL = Vout/Iout;

e11 = 1/Cr; e12 = (-1/Lr)+(Ls/((Lr^2)*k3));
e13 = -Ls/(Lm*Lr*k3);
e14 = n/CL;
e15 = -e14;

A1={{0,e11, 0, 0,0},
   {e12, 0, 0,0, 0},
   {e13, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, e14,e15, 0,0},
   {0,0 ,0 ,0 e16,0}};
(*A1 // MatrixForm*)

b11 =(1/Lr)-(Ls/((Lr^2)*k3));
b12 = -k1 + ((k1+k2)/k3)*(Ls/Lr);
b13= Ls/(Lm*Lr*k3);
b14 = k2 -(((k1+k2)/k3)*(Ls/Lm));
b15 = -1/(RL*CL*k);
b16 = -ki;

B1= {{0, 0},
     {b11, b12},
     {b13, b14},
     {0,      b15},
     {0,      b16}};
(*B1 // MatrixForm*)

e21 =1/Cr;
e22 = -1/(Lr+Lm);
e23= e22;
e24 = ki*k;

A2 = {{0, e21, 0,0, 0},
      {e22, 0,0,0,0},
     {e23,0 ,0,0,0},
     {0,0,0,0,0},
     {0,0,0,e24,0}};
(*A2 // MatrixForm*)

b21=1/(Lr+Lm);
b22 = b21;
b23 = -1/(RL*CL*k);
b24 = -ki;

B2 ={{0, 0},
     {b21, 0},
     {b22 ,0},
     {0, b23},
     {0, b24}};
(*B2 // MatrixForm*)


xt0 = {xt01,xt02,xt03,xt04,xt05};
xt1 = {xt11,xt12,xt13,xt14,xt15};
xt2 = {xt21,xt22,xt23,xt24,xt25};

W1 = { {-1, 0,0,0,0},
      {0, -1, 0,0,0},
      {0,0, -1, 0,0},
      {0,0,0,1,0},
     {0,0,0,0,1}}; 
W2 = {Vin,0,0,0,0}; 
W3 = {0,1,0,0,0};
W4 = {0,0,1,0,0};
W5 = {0,0,0,k,0};
W6 = {0,0,0,0,1};

(*list = {xt2 == W1.xt0+W2,
          W3.xt1 == W4.xt1,
       2*t2*(f0+Kp*(W5.xt2-Vref)+W6.xt2) == 1,
        xt1 ==MatrixExp[A1*t1].xt0+( Integrate[MatrixExp[A1*(t1-sig)],{sig,0,t1}]).(B1).u,
       xt2 ==MatrixExp[A2*(t2-t1)].xt1+( Integrate[MatrixExp[A2*(t2-sig)],{sig,t1,t2}]).(B2).u};*)
  eq1 = Solve[xt2 == W1.xt0+W2] /. Rule -> Equal;
  eq2 = Solve[W3.xt1 == W4.xt1]/. Rule -> Equal; 
  eq3 = Solve[2*t2*(f0+Kp*(W5.xt2-Vref)+W6.xt2) == 1]/. Rule -> Equal;
  eq4 = Solve[xt1 ==MatrixExp[A1*t1].xt0+( Integrate[MatrixExp[A1*(t1-sig)],{sig,0,t1}]).(B1).u]/. Rule -> Equal;
  eq5 = Solve[xt2 ==MatrixExp[A2*(t2-t1)].xt1+( Integrate[MatrixExp[A2*(t2-sig)],{sig,t1,t2}]).(B2).u]/. Rule -> Equal;
  system = Flatten[Join[eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5]] 
  Solve[system,{xt01,xt02,xt03,xt04,xt05,xt11,xt12,xt13,xt14,xt15,xt21,xt22,xt23,xt24,xt25}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the code.

Comment: Thanks for the code. If you print `eq4` I believe you will see that is `{}` and that is probably bad. If you print `eq5` I believe you will see that is `Solve[...]` because it could not solve it given the input and that is probably bad. Your use of `Solve` worries me. Usually that is `Solve[expression,var]` but you do `Solve[expression]` with no var. Did you know that `eq4` was returning an empty list? Can you figure out why? Did you know that `eq5` wasn't solving? Can you figure out why? That seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at these points.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I don't think using Solve for eq4 and eq5 will work. I think the Integrate of a matrix is too complicate for Solve. Do you have any suggestions on a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: I would try turning the matrix integrate into a list of equations to solve. I would try using `Reduce`. I would search mathematica.stackexchange for carefully chosen words to find how other people have done this. If none of those work then I'd try Google searches to find how other people have done this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.